# scale_colour_manual R ggplot2 geom_tile() missing something?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, heatmap

G'day Everyone,

I am having a trouble figuring out how to specify the 'fill' colours for my graphs (below).

The different subsets of my data have different levels when I specify my 'fill' variable, e.g. one subset has 2 levels, and the other two have three levels. When I tell my plot to use the variable to 'fill' my graphs colours I get different colours between my graphs. I have tried to specify which colours my 'fill' variable levels should use but it hasn't worked. I have tried using multiple rearrangements of scale_colour_manual(), and a few other things I found around SO, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Could someone please point out where I am going wrong, when trying to specify my colours. Below is a representation of the code I am using and an image of my problem.

```
# Code to post on Stack overflow to see where I am going wrong with scale_colour_manual()
data <- data.frame('id' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'), 
               'treatment' = c('1', '1', '1','1', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2','2', '2', '2','2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3'), 
               'loci' = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'), 
               'assign' = c('0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1'))

a <- data[which(data$id == 'a'),]
b <- data[which(data$id == 'b'),]
c <- data[which(data$id == 'c'),]

aheat <- ggplot(a, aes(as.factor(loci), as.factor(treatment), fill = factor(assign))) + 
  geom_tile(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Number of Loci") + 
  ylab("Treatment") +
  ggtitle("A Plot") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 320, size = 6, vjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = a$assign, values = c('0' = 'blue', '1' = 'green'))
aheat

bheat <- ggplot(b, aes(as.factor(loci), as.factor(treatment), fill = factor(assign))) + 
  geom_tile(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Number of Loci") + 
  ylab("Treatment") +
  ggtitle("B Plot") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 320, size = 6, vjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = b$assign, values = c('0' = 'blue', '1' = 'green', '2' = 'red'))
bheat

cheat <- ggplot(c, aes(as.factor(loci), as.factor(treatment), fill = factor(assign))) + 
  geom_tile(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Number of Loci") + 
  ylab("Treatment") +
  ggtitle("C Plot") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 320, size = 6, vjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c$assign, values = c('0' = 'blue', '1' = 'green', '2' = 'red'))
cheat
```

[image]

Thanks for all the help!

Regards,
Adam

Comment: As you are setting fill= then use scale_fill_manual() to set colors, not the scale_color_manual().

Comment: Thanks Didzis. One of those super obvious things that I kept on missing.

Answer (score 0):

We have to make sure the colours are really used as fillings. Two solutions:

- Use `scale_fill_manual()` as suggested by @Didzis_Elfert. See first chart.
- Using `scale_color_manual()` is not wrong but we have to add the argument `aesthetics = "fill"`. See charts 2 and 3.

```r
# Setup
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(id = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c'),
                   treatment = c('1', '1', '1','1', '1', '1','1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2','2', '2', '2','2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3'),
                   loci = c('1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3'),
                   assign = c('0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '2', '0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '2', '1', '1', '1'))

a <- data[which(data$id == 'a'),]
b <- data[which(data$id == 'b'),]
c <- data[which(data$id == 'c'),]
```

```r
# Chart 1: scale_fill_manual
aheat <- ggplot(a, aes(as.factor(loci), as.factor(treatment), fill = factor(assign))) +
  geom_tile(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Number of Loci") +
  ylab("Treatment") +
  ggtitle("A Plot") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 320, size = 6, vjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = a$assign, values = c('0' = 'blue', '1' = 'green'))
aheat
```

[image]

```r
# Chart 2: scale_color_manual
bheat <- ggplot(b, aes(as.factor(loci), as.factor(treatment), fill = factor(assign))) +
  geom_tile(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Number of Loci") +
  ylab("Treatment") +
  ggtitle("B Plot") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 320, size = 6, vjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = b$assign, values = c('0' = 'blue', '1' = 'green', '2' = 'red'),
                     aesthetics = "fill")
bheat
```

[image]

```r
# Chart 3: scale_color_manual
cheat <- ggplot(c, aes(as.factor(loci), as.factor(treatment), fill = factor(assign))) +
  geom_tile(colour = 'white') +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Number of Loci") +
  ylab("Treatment") +
  ggtitle("C Plot") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 320, size = 6, vjust = 0.5), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 8)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c$assign, values = c('0' = 'blue', '1' = 'green', '2' = 'red'),
                     aesthetics = c("fill"))
cheat
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>